# Migrate listagg to string_agg(oracle -> postgres) including specific statements like ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I have a sub select that aggregates stuff together in oracle syntax. It looks a bit like this:

```
SELECT
    tbl.id AS id,
    listagg(tbl.NAME, '; ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE '...') WITHIN GROUP (
    ORDER BY tbl.NAME,
    '; ') AS Name
FROM
    schema.table tbl
```

How would I go about migrating this bit to `string_agg` on postgres? And how would I do on overflow truncate using `string_agg`?

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like

```
string_agg(tbl.NAME, '; ' ORDER BY tbl.name)
```

You wouldn't have to worry about overflow, since a string can be up to 1GB in PostgreSQL. But you can certainly truncate the result and append an ellipsis.